# Select highest data from value using key of a map - Java

Tags: java, date, dictionary, arraylist

I have a Map which contains date and a product release type.

Example ("2015/04/12","1|Prod43");

My Map Values:

```
2015/08/27  1|Prod23
2015/12/15  1|Prod55
2016/04/08  1|Prod09
2016/04/09  2|Prod09
2016/04/12  3|Prod09
```

I want to maintain 2 arrayLists, `dateList` to contain keys, `prodList` for values. But the constraint is, in the Month of April there are three releases for Prod09, which is denoted by number before the "|" symbol. I want only the latest release of the product for any month.

Here, April has 3 releases, i want to take only the 3rd release into my arrayList.

Need my arrayList to be like :

```
dateList -> ["2015/08/27","2015/12/15","2016/04/12"]
prodList - >["1|Prod23","1|Prod55","3|Prod09"]
```

Code:

```
{
Map<String,String> dateMap = new TreeMap<String,String>();
            dateMap.put("2015/08/27","1|Prod23");
            dateMap.put("2015/12/15","1|Prod55");
            dateMap.put("2016/04/08","1|Prod09");
            dateMap.put("2016/04/09","2|Prod09");
            dateMap.put("2016/04/12","3|Prod09");
            String test1="";
            String test2="";
            int count=0;
            List<String> prodList = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> dateList = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : dateMap.entrySet()) 
                        {   
                            String key = entry.getKey().substring(0,7);
                            String dateValue = entry.getValue();

                            if(("").equals(test1)){
                                test1=key;
                                test2=key;
                            }
                            if(!(test2.equals(key))){
                                dateList.add(key);
                                prodList.add(dateValue);
                                test2=key;
                            }else{
                                if(count<1){
                                dateList.add(key);
                                prodList.add(dateValue);
                                test2=key;
                                count++;
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    System.out.println("dateList: "+dateList);
                    System.out.println("prodList: "+prodList);
}
```

In the above approach i have done it for finding maximum of 2nd latest release, but if the releases are increased, this approach will fail. Can anyone please suggest me a better approach to do this. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: what if two products released on a particular date?? In a map key should be unique.

Comment: That wont happen in my scenario, the values of my map are populated from DB table, in which date is the Primary Key. so the possibility could be different dates from same month. Could you help

Comment: Your input keys in above code are incorrect. Maybe you would like to revisit them again?

Comment: @Aakash corrected them. Now can you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `TreeMap`, which is sorted according to the natural ordering of it's keys, we can use this property to write some code. I could come up quickly with this code, maybe it could help you

```
Map<String, String> dateMap = new TreeMap<String, String>();
dateMap.put("2015/08/27", "1|Prod23");
dateMap.put("2015/12/15", "1|Prod55");
dateMap.put("2016/04/08", "1|Prod09");
dateMap.put("2016/04/12", "3|Prod09");
dateMap.put("2016/04/09", "2|Prod09");

String lastKey = "";
String currentKey = "";
List<String> date = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> release = new ArrayList<String>();
for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : dateMap.entrySet()) {
    String temp = entry.getKey();
    currentKey = temp.substring(0, 7);
    if(currentKey.equals(lastKey)){ // another release in same month as previous release
        // Remove last release details
        date.remove(date.size() - 1);
        release.remove(release.size() - 1);
        // Add current release deetails
        date.add(temp);
        release.add(entry.getValue());
        lastKey = currentKey;
    } else { // first release in this month
        // Add current release deetails
        date.add(temp);
        release.add(entry.getValue());
        lastKey = currentKey;
    }
}
```

Maybe you code come up with more refined version from this. Below is the output of above code

```
[2015/08/27, 2015/12/15, 2016/04/12]
[1|Prod23, 1|Prod55, 3|Prod09]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Very useful, although i used a comparator method along with Treemap<>, since it is case-sensitive.

Comment: String comparison is by default case-sensitive, so to have bypass that, certainly you had to use a comparator.

Answer (score 3):

Couple observations:

- Your concatenation with the "|" character shows that you try to keep 2 pieces of data in a single value. (This is bad information practice, if you really need both, rather create a new class with a field for each value. Or you could use the index of a list as an implicit value of relative rank as I have done below).
- Maps (and other data structures) can keep **any** object, including `java.util.Date` (or one of the more modern time classes), arrays, `List`s, etc.
- It is not clear why you would want to map from date to product release.

For purposes of your question, a structure similar to the following map may be more useful:

{Product => [ReleaseDate1, ReleaseDate2, ...] }

where Product may be "Prod23","Prod55","Prod09" etc. and the value of the map would be a `List` or array, possibly empty. (`List`s are easier to add to).

To get the date of the latest release of "Prod12", you would do something like:

```
dates = prodMap.get("Prod12");
lastDate = dates.get(dates.size()); // assuming they where inserted in order
```

There are sorted collections (or you could provide a Comparator) that would ensure the order of the collection.

Comment: @ fr13d Thank you! Here i dont want to collect all the release dates of a single product, as the latest release would contain all the necessary info, so i want to remove the previous releases and keep only the latest one. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: @Disera, if you want to keep only the latest release date, don't keep a `List` (or other `Collection`), simply keep a `Date` as value in the map, and overwrite each time a new release date is available. Products not yet released will have `null`.

Comment: @Disera You should have made this requirement in your Question. It changes the entire problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a List of `String` to keep dates, I will prefer to prepare a List of `Date`. Converting a `String` to `Date` is not that difficult unless you have the same format.

This will help you converting the current format provided in your question code.

```
        DateFormat format  = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
        Date       date   = format.parse("2016/04/26");
```

And here is the function that will help you getting the latest date out of any number of provided dates.

```
    public static Date findLatest (Date... dates) {
        Date date = dates[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < dates.length; i++) {
            if (dates[i].after(date)) {
                date = dates[i];
            }
        }
        return date;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

## Question Redefined

The author of this Question redefined the problem statement in a comment on [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36934952/642706). Only the latest date per product is needed.

## java.time

Java 8 and later includes the java.time framework. These date-time classes supplant the poorly designed and troublesome old date-time classes such as java.util.Date/.Calendar. The new classes include [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) for a date-only value, and the [`YearMonth`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) class which is handy for organizing data by entire month rather than a single date.

## Map product code to date

Given the revised problem, track the latest date for each product, we need a [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) where the product code is the key and the latest date, a [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html), is the value.

```
Map< String , LocalDate > map = new HashMap<>();
```

If you can get your input data to use standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format for the dates, we can very simply enter data.

```
map.put( "Prod23" , LocalDate.parse( "2015-08-27" ) );
map.put( "Prod55" , LocalDate.parse( "2015-12-15" ) );
map.put( "Prod09" , LocalDate.parse( "2016-04-08" ) );
```

Now we are about to put a different, newer, date in for the same `Prod09` key. The `Map` replaces the previous value (`LocalDate` for "2016-04-08") with a fresh value (`LocalDate` for "2016/04/09"). To quote the doc of [`Map::put`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put-K-V-):

> If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced by the specified value.

```
map.put( "Prod09" , LocalDate.parse( "2016-04-09" ) );
```

And replace it again with an even later date, the 12th of April.

```
map.put( "Prod09" , LocalDate.parse( "2016-04-12" ) );
```

## `merge` versus `put`

This approach so far assumes the incoming data is always for later dates, arriving in chronological order. If the data may include earlier dates, but we always want to keep the latest date, then we have a problem. To see the problem, we can switch two lines, putting the 9th of April after the 12th.

```
// Calling `put` with dates arriving *not* in chronological-order.
Map< String , LocalDate> mapP = new HashMap<> ();

mapP.put ( "Prod23" , LocalDate.parse ( "2015-08-27" ) );
mapP.put ( "Prod55" , LocalDate.parse ( "2015-12-15" ) );
mapP.put ( "Prod09" , LocalDate.parse ( "2016-04-08" ) );
mapP.put ( "Prod09" , LocalDate.parse ( "2016-04-12" ) );
mapP.put ( "Prod09" , LocalDate.parse ( "2016-04-09" ) );

System.out.println ( "mapP: " + mapP );
```

You can see in the output that the 9th replaced the 12th, not what we want.

> mapP: {Prod23=2015-08-27, Prod55=2015-12-15, Prod09=2016-04-09}

The fix is to define a comparison function to be applied each time we attempt adding to the `Map`. The `Map` interface defines the [`merge`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) method for this purpose, where we pass an implementation of [`BiFunction`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiFunction.html). Sounds fancy, but actually quite simple to implement. One line of code using a [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#Java), inside some [Lambda syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) new in Java 8 and later.

We define our `BiFunction` to compare a pair of `LocalDate` objects, and return whichever one is later ([`isAfter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#isAfter-java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate-) the other). If the same, it does not matter which we return as either will do.

With our `BiFunction` defined, we call [`merge`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) rather than [`put`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put-K-V-) on our `Map`.

```
// Calling `merge` with dates arriving *not* in chronological-order.
Map< String , LocalDate> mapM = new HashMap<> ();

BiFunction<LocalDate , LocalDate , LocalDate> latestLocalDate = ( ld1 , ld2 ) -> {
    return ( ld1.isAfter ( ld2 ) ? ld1 : ld2 );
};

mapM.merge ( "Prod23" , LocalDate.parse ( "2015-08-27" ) , latestLocalDate );
mapM.merge ( "Prod55" , LocalDate.parse ( "2015-12-15" ) , latestLocalDate );
mapM.merge ( "Prod09" , LocalDate.parse ( "2016-04-08" ) , latestLocalDate );
mapM.merge ( "Prod09" , LocalDate.parse ( "2016-04-12" ) , latestLocalDate );
mapM.merge ( "Prod09" , LocalDate.parse ( "2016-04-09" ) , latestLocalDate );

System.out.println ( "mapM: " + mapM );
```

In this output, you can see the 9th did *not* replace the 12th of April. The 9th was ignored, and the 12th stayed in place as our latest value for the key of `Prod09`.

> mapM: {Prod23=2015-08-27, Prod55=2015-12-15, Prod09=2016-04-12}

## Formatting pattern

To parse the input data as shown in the Question, define a [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) object, and pass into the call to `parse`.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "yyyy/MM/dd" );
… LocalDate.parse( "2015/08/27" , formatter ) …
```